# I want to loop in an array in the state and check if the input is exist in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, state

I tried to build this method addgamer() to check if the username exists in the gamers array onClick add button and if he is , i want it don't add his info as an object in the array, i want to know why it didn't work ?
....i created this enterdata() method to get the values of these three gamer info onChange the values of their inputs

```
class App extends Component {
  state= {
    gamer:{
          FirstName:"",
          LastName: "",
          UserName: "",
    },
    gamers:[],
  }

  enterdata = (event)=> {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    this.setState((prevstate)=>({
        gamer: {...prevstate.gamer,[name] : value},  
    }))
  }
  
  addgamer = (event) =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  for(let i = 0;i<this.state.gamers.length; i++){
    if(this.state.gamer.UserName === this.state.gamers[i].UserName){
        return false; 
    }else{
        this.setState(prevstate =>({
        gamers: [...prevstate.gamers, this.state.gamer],
        gamer: {FirstName:"", LastName: "", UserName: ""},
  }))
    }
  }  
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are adding the gamer every time the username is not found. What you should do is set a flag to see whether the username was found in the gamers list or not, and *then* do the `setState` to add the new gamer if the username was not found, like so:

```
let found = false;
for(let i = 0;i<this.state.gamers.length; i++){
    if(this.state.gamer.UserName === this.state.gamers[i].UserName){
        found = true;
        break;
    }   
}
// alternatively: let found = this.state.gamers.find(gamer => this.state.gamer.UserName === gamer.UserName)
if (!found) {
    this.setState(prevstate =>({
        gamers: [...prevstate.gamers, this.state.gamer],
        gamer: {FirstName:"", LastName: "", UserName: ""},
    }))
}
```